# Trying to iterate through a string to find a substring but keep getting a TypeError: must be str, not int on -> if s[i: i+3] == 'bob':

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: must be str, not int on -> if s[i: i+3] == 'bob':
```

when executing the following code:

```
number_of_times = 0

i=0

for i in s:

  if s[i: i+3] == 'bob':

    number_of_times += 1

print(str(number_of_times))
```

Could anybody please explain why?

Comment: Are you assigning a string to the variable 's' ?  Also, in print(str(number_of_times)), you could directly print that variable instead of converting it into an int.

Comment: Thanks that's a good tip, was possibly thinking of concatenating a sentence later on. Also yes was assigning a string to 's'.

Comment: Please show all your code as code and normal text as normal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is change your `for loop` as :

```
for i in range(len(s)):                   #point of interest
   if s[i: i+3] == 'bob':
      number_of_times += 1
```

Here, when you do `for i in s` , your value of `i` is `char`.

For ex :

```
s="bob"
for i in s:
    print(i)
#b
#o
#b
```

So when you do `s[i]`, you are basically doing something like `s['b']` , which is wrong.

Anyways, its better to use `find`, an inbuilt function to **find the** `starting index` of your `substring`. If not found, it returns `-1`.

Ex :

```
>>> s="hi i am bob !"
>>> s.find('bob')
=>  8
```

Or, if you want to **count the number of times a substring occurs**, use `count`, another inbuilt funciton.

Ex :

```
>>> s="hi bob ! bob is a man" 
>>> s.count('bob')
=> 2
```

Comment: Well, OP is assigning i = 0 in line number 2, how can that be treated as a char?

Comment: How is that a problem? Python is `dynamic` in nature after all.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, this seems to have worked. Do you perhaps know why "for i in s: " didn't work in the first instance?

Comment: I have answered that in my post. Pls go through it once again.

Comment: Thanks v-much! Makes a lot of sense. I had been stuck on this for some time (still learning) and looked at numerous posts with similar errors (where the code is a lot more difficult to understand). Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.

Comment: Accepted, apologies - first time on here. Thanks again.

Comment: @KaushikNP thanks, mate! Learnt something new today.